# Show text based on selected option in combobox Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have combobox with a few options and I need it to show corresponding text when a certain option is selected. For example if a user selects "Option 1", "Option 2" or "Option 3" etc he should also see a some text below the combobox explaining what selecting the certain option does. Can someone explain to me what a good method would be to achieve this?

This an example of my fields and how I tried to store the options and the explanations.

```
items: [
    {
        itemId: 'type-label',
        margin: '0 0 20 0'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        queryMode: 'local',
        itemId: 'type',
        width: '70%',
        allowBlank: false,
        displayField: 'text',
        valueField: 'value',
        value: {text: 'Option 1', value: 'value_1'},
        bind: {
            store: [
                {
                    text: 'Option 1',
                    value: 'value_1'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Option 2',
                    value: 'value_2'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Option 3',
                    value: 'value_3'
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        cls: 'select-fieldset',
        itemId: 'combobox-text',
        hidden: true,
        items: [
            {
                itemId: 'option-1-label',
                bind: {
                    html: 'helper text explaining what selection "Option 1" does'
                },
                margin: '0 0 10 0'
            },
            {
                itemId: 'option-2-label',
                bind: {
                    html: 'helper text explaining what selection "Option 2" does'
                },
                margin: '0 0 10 0'
            },
             {
                itemId: 'option-3-label',
                bind: {
                    html: 'helper text explaining what selection "Option 3" does'
                },
                margin: '0 0 10 0'
            },
        ]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a listener on the `change` event for the  [combobox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-change) and show the info label according to the new Value.

I set up a Sencha fiddle for you were I did something similar.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37j2